# gsoap class generation problem

Tags: xml, wsdl, gsoap

I am trying to generate gsoap classes for the JIRA issue tracking system WSDL.  I run these commands to generate the required classes:

```
$ wsdl2h -o JIRASoap.h <url to wsdl>
$ soapcpp2 -C JIRASoap.h
```

The soapcpp2 command gives the following output, but does not indicate how to fix it.

```
There were errors:
3 syntax errors
1 semantic error
2 warnings
```

These are (most of) the errors:

```
JIRASoap.h(935): syntax error
JIRASoap.h(934): Syntax error: input before ; skipped
JIRASoap.h(940): syntax error
JIRASoap.h(939): Syntax error: input before ; skipped

JIRASoap.h(942): **ERROR**: Duplicate declaration of __size (already declarared at line 937)

JIRASoap.h(947): syntax error
JIRASoap.h(946): Syntax error: input before ; skipped
```

Here is the relevant portion of JIRASoap.h (lines 928-947):

```
/// SOAP encoded array of xs:byte[]
class ArrayOf_USCORExsd_USCOREbase64Binary
{ public:
/// SOAP encoded array of xs:byte
class 
{ public:
/// Pointer to array of xsd__byte.
    xsd__byte                           *__ptr                         ;
/// Size of the dynamic array.
    int                                  __size                        ;
/// Offset for partially transmitted arrays (uncomment only when required).
//  int                                  __offset                      ;
    }                                   *__ptr                         ;
/// Size of the dynamic array.
    int                                  __size                        ;
/// Offset for partially transmitted arrays (uncomment only when required).
//  int                                  __offset                      ;
/// A handle to the soap struct that manages this instance (automatically set)
    struct soap                         *soap                          ;
};
```

When I try to compile my program, I get this error:

> soapStub.h:2799: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘ArrayOf_USCORExsd_USCOREbase64Binary’ with no type

Here is the relevant section of the WSDL:

```
<complexType name="ArrayOf_xsd_base64Binary">
  <complexContent>
    <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
      <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:byte[][]"/>
    </restriction>
  </complexContent>
</complexType>
```

As far as I can tell, most types are defined in soapStub.h, but ArrayOf_USCORExsd_USCOREbase64Binary is not.

When I generate C only files, I get "struct /*?*/" instead of "ArrayOf_USCORExsd_USCOREbase64Binary".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the code to compile by removing all references to ArrayOf_USCORExsd_USCOREbase64Binary from JIRASoap.h, including the class itself and the ns4_addAttachmentsToIssue method (which takes a pointer to an ArrayOf_USCORExsd_USCOREbase64Binary as a parameter).

If you find a way to fix the errors above without removing the ns4_addAttachmentsToIssue, please let me know.